# Android can't include linux in C program with Android.mk

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, android.mk

I'm trying to compile a C program for Android 6. This is my `Android.mk`:

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-23
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
# Enable PIE manually. Will get reset on $(CLEAR_VARS). This
# is what enabling PIE translates to behind the scenes.
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -fPIE -DHAVE_FANOTIFY=1 -DHAVE_SYS_FANOTIFY=0
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -fPIE -pie
# give module name
LOCAL_MODULE := fsmon
# list your C files to compile
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := inotify.c fanotify.c util.c main.c
# this option will build executables instead of building library for android application.
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

In the `fanotify.c` following include is written:

```
#include <linux/fanotify.h>
```

When I try to use `ndk-build`, following error appears:

```
fsmon/jni/fanotify.c:51:10: fatal error: 'linux/fanotify.h' file not found
#include <linux/fanotify.h>
         ^
```

The header `fanotify.h` is present in the ndk path `/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/linux`

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Same error if I try to include `sys/fanotify.h`

Comment: Hmm okay it's not present in `ndk-bundle/platforms/android-23/arch-arm/usr/include/linux` ... how can I tell it to use it from sysroot/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify additional include paths for your module using `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES`.

`LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := /Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/`

https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk.html#mdv

Comment: Okay thanks, this works. But now I get 5 errors: `/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include/asm/signal.h:101:3: error: typedef redefinition with different types ('struct
      (anonymous struct at /Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include/asm/signal.h:97:16)' vs 'struct sigaltstack')
} stack_t;`
Then I included api 23, but then 3 errors appear: `Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-23/arch-arm/usr/include/signal.h:87:12: error: duplicate member '_u'` do you have an idea? `

Comment: I think your design is probably not right - either you're including different versions of the same include files or you're including different include files which have the same definitions. But I guess, from the state you've now progressed to, you should probably try to debug the errors one-by-one by removing header file duplication or definition duplication.

Comment: Hm yes it's strange, because the 64bit executable files get created.. It's only a problem with the 32bit versions. It's also strange how the header files get link from sysroot to the android-9 api. I tried now a lot of variations, but no success... Maybe I will create another question for this problem, the other one with the non finding library was solved.

Comment: So here if you can figure out something... but thanks for the other answer! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43140359/android-ndk-build-cant-build-32bit-executable-file

Comment: Sure, I'll go through the question and try to help if I can!

Comment: You should not do this. You're mixing and matching the old headers and the new headers. It's not a tested configuration and as you can see that leads to other issues, since you're now actually mixing some very up to date headers with some very out of date headers. See my answer for the correct way to get the up to date headers.

Answer (score 0):

The NDK historically didn't backport headers to old releases, but we've reworked things in r14 so this is possible: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/ndk-r14-release/docs/UnifiedHeaders.md

By default in r14 you still get the old form of the headers. The new "unified headers" have the headers you're looking for. If you want to try unified headers, set `APP_UNIFIED_HEADERS := true` in your Application.mk (settings for other build systems can be found in the link above).

In r15 (first beta due out soon), the default has changed to the new headers, and the option for disabling them has changed (see the same doc in r15 for changes in options: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/ndk-r15-release/docs/UnifiedHeaders.md).